# Applet won't work in browser

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, security, applet

Okay I know there are a lot of questions about this and a lot of answers but I really haven't had any luck with any of them. I have a multi-class, multi-package program that also uses some external libraries (as jar files). I exported my project as a jar file as well and below is my "index.html" that references the necessary libraries and my jar file. All those files have been put in the same directory and I can see the applet on my webpage: http://easlnx01.eas.muohio.edu/~whitetc2/Twitter%20Mining%202/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Java Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
This is my page<br>
Below you see an applet<br>
<br>
<applet codebase ="." code="main.BasicGUI.class"
    archive="twitter.jar, jsch-0-1.1.48.jar, twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar, sftp.jar"
    height="600" width="450"/>
</applet>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My main class (BasicGUI.java) extends JApplet and calls a variety of other classes based on input. It has the public void init() as well. Can anyone please tell me why this isn't totally working? Here is a link to my site where it is uploaded: http://easlnx01.eas.muohio.edu/~whitetc2/Twitter%20Mining%202/

As you can see the applet comes up but now the options panel in the file tab won't work and the program itself doesn't actually function.

Here is my main BasicGUI.java class:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

import com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpException;

import Twitter.SearchTweets;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/** 
 *  The GUI for our Twitter Widget. Plans are to eventually
 *  set this up with a Java Applet to run straight from the 
 *  CC teams website.
 *  @author Taylor White and Alex Meyer
 */
public class BasicGUI extends JApplet{

    //Auto-generated 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Aesthetic options, have getters and setters to allow for communication across GUIs
    private static int opposite;
    private static int maxTweets = 100;
    private static boolean sortByLocation = false;
    private static boolean isOptionsOpen = false;

    // Options GUI, initiated here to avoid multiple open windows
    //private OptionsGUI options;

    // Initialize all swing objects.
    private JPanel northSubPnl1; 
    private JPanel northSubPnl2;
    private JPanel northSubPnl3;
    private JPanel northPnl;
    private JPanel eastPnl;
    private JPanel westPnl;
    private JLabel myQuery;

    /** TWITTER INITILIAZATIONS **/
    private static Twitter.TwitterDataList tweets;
    /** END TWITTER INITIALIZATIONS **/

    // Buttons
    private JButton queryBtn; // Submits the query
    private JButton uploadBtn;

    // TextField Query
    private JTextField txtQuery; // USER Query

    // Menu
    private JMenuBar mb; // Menu bar
    private JMenu mnuFile; // File Entry on Menu bar
    private JMenuItem mnuFileOpen;
    private JMenuItem mnuFileSave;
    private JMenuItem mnuFileOptions;
    private JMenuItem mnuItemQuit; // Quit sub item
    private JMenu mnuHelp; // Help Menu entry
    private JMenuItem mnuItemAbout; // About Entry

    //West Panel stuff
    private static JList list;
    private JScrollPane listScroller;
    private JLabel uploadText;
    private JCheckBox uploadHTML;
    private JCheckBox uploadXML;
    private JCheckBox uploadJSON;

    //East Panel stuff
    private JTextArea user;
    private static JTextArea sysStatus;
    private JScrollPane statusScroll;
    private static JTextArea settings;
    private static String keywords;

    /*
     * Getters and setters for aesthetic options
     */
    public static boolean isSortedByLocation() {
        return sortByLocation;
    }

    public static void setSortedByLocation(boolean toSort) {
        sortByLocation = toSort;
    }

    public static int getMaxTweets() {
        return maxTweets;
    }

    public static void setMaxTweets(int num) {
        maxTweets = num;
    }

    public static boolean isOptionsOpen() {
        return isOptionsOpen;
    }

    public static void setOptionsOpen(boolean option) {
        isOptionsOpen = option;
    }

    /*
     * CONSTRUCTOR
     */
    public void init() {
        sysStatus = new JTextArea (1, 20);
        sysStatus.setEditable(false);
        northSubPnl1 = new JPanel(); 
        northSubPnl2 = new JPanel();
        northSubPnl3 = new JPanel();
        northPnl = new JPanel();
        eastPnl = new JPanel();
        westPnl = new JPanel();
        myQuery = new JLabel ("You have no queries yet");

        // TwitterDataList
        tweets = new Twitter.TwitterDataList ();

        // Buttons
        queryBtn = new JButton("Submit Query"); // Submits the query
        uploadBtn = new JButton("Upload Tweets"); // Uploads both XML and HTML files.

        // TextField Query
        txtQuery = new JTextField(); // USER Query

        // Menu
        mb = new JMenuBar(); // Menu bar
        mnuFile = new JMenu("File");
        mnuFileOpen = new JMenuItem("Open"); 
        mnuFileSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
        mnuFileOptions = new JMenuItem("Options");
        mnuItemQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit"); 
        mnuHelp = new JMenu("Help"); 
        mnuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("About"); 

        //West Panel stuff
        String[] tweetsString = new String[2000];
        list = new JList (tweetsString);
        uploadText = new JLabel("Upload as:");
        uploadHTML = new JCheckBox("HTML", false);
        uploadXML = new JCheckBox("XML", false);
        uploadJSON = new JCheckBox("JSON", false);

        //East Panel stuff
        user = new JTextArea("Username: ");
        keywords = new String ();
        statusScroll = new JScrollPane(sysStatus);
        statusScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
        statusScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(statusScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
        settings = new JTextArea(1, 20);


        // Set menu bar
        this.setJMenuBar(mb);

        //Build Menus
        this.buildMenus();
        // West Panel
        this.westPnlSetup();
        // East Panel
        this.eastPnlSetup();
        // Add objects to respective panels
        this.northPnlSetup();
        // Setup Main Frame
        this.setLayout();
        // Add Listeners
        this.addListeners();

        //Finish Launch
        Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
        Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        int width = (int)dim.getWidth();
        int height = (int)dim.getHeight();;                     //worry about location later. This is fine for testing purposes
        this.setBounds(width/2-400, height/2-400, 500, 800);    //Arbitrarily chosen for a 1600 by 900 screen 
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == queryBtn) {        
                if (txtQuery.getText().length() > 2) {
                    myQuery.setText("Your current query: " + txtQuery.getText());
                    tweets = Twitter.SearchTweets.customSearch(txtQuery.getText()); // SEARCH
                    if (SearchTweets.getKeywords() != null) {
                        if (tweets.getSize() > 0)
                            tweets = Twitter.SearchTweets.sortByKeyword(tweets, SearchTweets.getKeywords()); // Sort right after.
                        else {
                            print("No tweets found!");
                            System.out.println("No tweets found!");
                        }
                    }
                    if (tweets.getSize() > 0) {
                        list.setListData(tweets.toArray(maxTweets));
                        sysStatus.append("Top Tweet: " + tweets.get(0).getTweet());
                        System.out.println("Top Tweet: " + tweets.get(0).getTweet());
                        //tweets.saveHTML(txtQuery.getText()); NOT SAVING BY DEFAULT ANY MORE
                    }
                    else {
                        print("No tweets found!");
                        System.out.println("No tweets found!");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("Please input at least a 3 letter word to begin a query.");
                    System.out.println("Please input at least a 3 letter word to begin a query.");
                }
            }

            // Not sure how to make directory path independent of system. change path to your local project to get open and save to work
            else if (e.getSource() == mnuFileOpen) {
                final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("C:/Users/Meyer/Desktop/YATE/DataCollection");
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(mnuFile);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    tweets = Twitter.TwitterDataList.load(file.getName());
                    if (SearchTweets.getKeywords() != null) {
                        tweets = Twitter.SearchTweets.sortByKeyword(tweets, SearchTweets.getKeywords());
                    }
                    list.setListData(tweets.toArray(maxTweets));
                    myQuery.setText("Your current query: " + file.getName());
                }
            }

            else if (e.getSource() == mnuFileSave) {
                final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("C:/Users/Meyer/Desktop/YATE/DataCollection");
                int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(mnuFile);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    tweets.writeHTML(file.getName());
                }
            }

            else if (e.getSource() == mnuFileOptions) {
                if (!isOptionsOpen()) {
                    new OptionsGUI();
                    setOptionsOpen(true);
                }           
            }

            else if (e.getSource() == uploadBtn) {
                if (uploadHTML.isSelected() || 
                        uploadXML.isSelected() || uploadJSON.isSelected()) {
                    try {
                        tweets.saveAll(txtQuery.getText(), uploadHTML.isSelected(), 
                                uploadXML.isSelected(), uploadJSON.isSelected());
                    } catch (SftpException exception) {
                        System.out.println("Could not upload. Try another time.");
                        print("Could not upload. Try another time.");
                    }
                }
                else if (tweets.getSize() ==0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no tweets to upload!");
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need to select a file type in order to upload.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class KeyChecker implements KeyListener {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
                queryBtn.doClick();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            //ignore
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            //ignore
        }
    }

    public class ListListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {    
            try {
                user.setText(tweets.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).toString());
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error) {
                user.setText(tweets.get(list.getFirstVisibleIndex()).toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListenMenuQuit implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);         
        }
    }

    public class ListenCloseWdw extends WindowAdapter{
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);         
        }
    }

    public void buildMenus () {
        mnuFile.add(mnuFileOpen);
        mnuFile.add(mnuFileSave);
        mnuFile.add(mnuFileOptions);
        mnuFile.add(mnuItemQuit);  // Create Quit line
        mnuHelp.add(mnuItemAbout); // Create About line
        mb.add(mnuFile);        // Add Menu items to form
        mb.add(mnuHelp);
    }


    /**
     * North Panel
     */
    public void northPnlSetup () {
        northPnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout (northPnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        northSubPnl1.add(txtQuery);
        northSubPnl1.add(queryBtn);
        txtQuery.setColumns(20);
        northPnl.add(northSubPnl1);

    }
    /**
     * Sets Layout of GUI
     */

    public void setLayout () {
        // Setup Main Frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(northPnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(westPnl, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.getContentPane().add(eastPnl, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    /*
     * Adds action listeners    
     */
    public void addListeners(){
        mnuItemQuit.addActionListener(new ListenMenuQuit());
        mnuFileOpen.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        mnuFileSave.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        mnuFileOptions.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        queryBtn.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        uploadBtn.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListListener());
        txtQuery.addKeyListener(new KeyChecker());

    }

    public void westPnlSetup () {
        westPnl.add(new JLabel ("Tweets"));
        westPnl.add(new JLabel("-------"));
        westPnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout (westPnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        list.setListData(tweets.toArray(maxTweets));
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        westPnl.add(listScroller);
        // setup upload button and panel for check boxes
        northSubPnl2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northSubPnl2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        northSubPnl2.add(uploadBtn);
        uploadBtn.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        northSubPnl2.add(uploadText);
        uploadText.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        northSubPnl2.add(northSubPnl3);
        // setup check boxes
        northSubPnl3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northSubPnl3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        northSubPnl3.add(uploadHTML);
        northSubPnl3.add(uploadXML);
        northSubPnl3.add(uploadJSON);
        westPnl.add(northSubPnl2);
    }

    public void eastPnlSetup () {
        eastPnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout (eastPnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel("Metadata"));
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel("-------"));
        user = new JTextArea(1, 20);
        user.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (200,50));
        user.setEditable(false);
        user.append("User: \n");
        user.append("Date: \n");
        user.append("Location: \n");
        user.append("Relevance: \n");
        user.append("Tweet: ");
        user.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        user.setLineWrap(true);
        eastPnl.add(user);
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel("Settings"));
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel(new JLabel("-------").getText()));
        String keywords = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < SearchTweets.getKeywords().size(); i++) {
            keywords = SearchTweets.getKeywords().get(i) + ", ";
        }
        try {
            keywords = keywords.substring(0, keywords.length()-2);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            keywords = ""; // There are no keywords if this happens.
        }

        /*
         * || THIS IS IF IN WHITE ||
         * ||                     ||
         * VV                     VV
         */
        settings.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (200,50));
        settings.setEditable(false);
        BasicGUI.setSettingsPaneValues();
        settings.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        settings.setLineWrap(true);
        eastPnl.add(settings);

        sysStatus.append(">");
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel("System Status       "));
        eastPnl.add(new JLabel(new JLabel("-------").getText()+"----"));
        sysStatus.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        sysStatus.setLineWrap(true);
        eastPnl.add(statusScroll);
        //this.redirectSystemStreams(); // REDIRECTS the text of console to the sysStatus box. NOT REAL TIME.

        /* END WHITE */
    }


    public static void setSettingsPaneValues () {
        keywords = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < SearchTweets.getKeywords().size(); i++) {
            keywords += SearchTweets.getKeywords().get(i) + ", ";
        }
        if (SearchTweets.getKeywords().size()== 0) {
            keywords = "none";
        }
        else {
            try {
                keywords = keywords.substring(0, keywords.length()-2);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                keywords = ""; // There are no keywords if this happens.
            }
        }

        settings.setText("Sort by location: " + isSortedByLocation() +
                "\nTimeout (in seconds): " + SearchTweets.getTimeout() + 
                "\nMaximum tweets shown: " + getMaxTweets() + 
                "\nKeywords: " + keywords);
        if (SearchTweets.getKeywords() != null && tweets.getSize() > 0) {
            tweets = Twitter.SearchTweets.sortByKeyword(tweets, SearchTweets.getKeywords());
        }
        list.setListData(tweets.toArray(maxTweets));
        list.repaint();
    }


    /**
     * returns string value of the keywords used
     * @return returns instance variable keywords
     * @author Taylor
     */
    public static String getKeywords () {
        return keywords;
    }
    /**
     * Updates the sysStatus textArea
     * @param text
     */
    private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                opposite++;
                opposite = opposite%2;
                if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(".")){ // So I can do the ". . ." sequence to signify waiting.
                    if (opposite%2 == 1) {
                        sysStatus.append("\n>" + text);
                    }
                    else sysStatus.append(text);
                }
                else sysStatus.append(text);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Allows other classes to print to sysStatus
     */
    public static void print (String text) {
        opposite++;
        opposite = opposite%2;
        if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase(".")){ // So I can do the ". . ." sequence to signify waiting.
            //if (opposite%2 == 1) {
            sysStatus.append("\n\n>" + text);
            sysStatus.repaint();
            //}
            //else sysStatus.append("\n" + text);
        }
        else sysStatus.append(text);

        sysStatus.invalidate();
        sysStatus.repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Redirects all console output to the textarea.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void redirectSystemStreams() {
        OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
        };

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added it, thanks. It was actually up at the top and I moved it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at twitter4j.TwitterFactory.<clinit>(TwitterFactory.java:76)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.<init>(HttpClientWrapper.java:48)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
        (java.util.PropertyPermission twitter4j.http.httpClient read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
```

Typically an applet operates in a restrictive security sand-box.  To get all properties or reach across sites, the applet needs to be digitally signed by you, and trusted by the end-user (they 'Click OK when prompted').

General tips:

1. Configure the Java Console to pop up when an applet loads.  You are 'flying blind' at the moment.
2. For broken code, ensure that **every** catch calls `Throwable.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Wow thats great to see what the error is. So if I 'sign my app' that will likely be the solution to our problem? We've known we were flying blind online we couldn't figure out how to get the console to be viewable, is there any way to do that? I tried to create my own PrintStream and redirect the console output but that didn't work.

Comment: I figured I would get that answer ha. Thank you Andrew.